# How to subclass an object with a var in its primary constructor

Tags: scala

I'm wanting to do something like this:

```
class A (var updateCount: Int) {
}

class B (val name: String, var updateCount: Int) extends A(updateCount) {
  def inc(): Unit = {
    updateCount = updateCount + 1
  }
}

var b = new B("a", 10)
println(b.name)
println(b.updateCount)

b.updateCount = 9999
b.inc
println(b.updateCount)
```

but the compiler doesn't like it.

```
(fragment of extend.scala):5: error: error overriding variable updateCount in class A of type Int;
 variable updateCount needs `override' modifier
class B (val name: String, var updateCount: Int) extends A(updateCount) {
```

Adding override on updateCount doesn't work either. What's the clean way to do this?

Comment: A couple of people have pointed out I should remove the var from updateCount in B. This doesn't work. If you try it, you should get

(fragment of extend.scala):7: error: reassignment to val
    updateCount = updateCount + 1

coming out of the inc method.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to declare the `var` in the subclass constructor signature:

```
class B (val name: String, /* note no var */ updateCount: Int) extends A(updateCount) {
  //...
}
```

This also extends to classes with `val`s in their constructors also:

```
scala> class C(val i: Int)
defined class C

scala> class D(j: Int) extends C(j)
defined class D
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I use the exact example I provided, removing the var from updateCount, I get

(fragment of extend.scala):7: error: reassignment to val
    updateCount = updateCount + 1

coming out of the inc method.

Comment: You'll just need to rename the parameters in class B: use `updateCountIn` in the constructor signature and call to class A's constructor; you'll still be able to access `updateCount` in the constructor/body of class B.

Answer (score 4):

You need to avoid having the identifier declared for `B` shadowing the identifier declared for `A`. The easiest way to do that is to chose a different name. If, however, you really, really don't want to do that, here is an alternative:

```
class B (val name: String, updateCount: Int) extends A(updateCount) {
  self: A =>
  def inc(): Unit = {
    self.updateCount = self.updateCount + 1
  }
}
```

And, by the way, drop the `var` from B declaration.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a work around. This seems like a strange limitation of the language. If I had a inheritance graph 5 deep, would I need to continue to come up with "fake" names for these args? updateCountDontUse1, and in its subclass updateCountDontUse2, etc? It's not just the name... it's the cruft, too. It's an extra field that's sitting in my class, begging someone to use it and get bad results.

Comment: That's the thing... the parameters to the class are not really fields, unless preceeded with `val` or `var`. If you do not use them anywhere but the constructor, they won't be stored as fields in the class.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `var` keyword in the parameters, this makes the value passed in be a new `var` in the class. When you don't do that, it makes it a constructor parameter (only), and you use it's value for the `var` by passing it to the constructor. So the example that people have given

```
class B(val name:String, updateCount:Int) extends A(updateCount)
```

is correct.

However, scala makes constructor parameters directly available to the methods in the class (I'm not sure why), so if you use the same name you will find that your code fails to compile with the error `reassignment to val` when you try to reassign the "var". For example in the following snippet, the immutable constructor parameter shadows the inherited `var` and so you can't assign to the parameter.

```
class B (val name: String, updateCount: Int) extends A(updateCount) {
  def inc(): Unit = {
    updateCount = updateCount + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: class B(val name:String, updateCount:Int) extends A(updateCount) will not compile for me. I get 

(fragment of extend.scala):7: error: reassignment to val
    updateCount = updateCount + 1

Comment: The first version compiles. The second version intentionally does not, and demonstrates the problem with using the same name for the var and the constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As others mention, your constructor param in B is shadowing the superclass' version.  Here's the code that works and doesn't require self-type:

```
class A (var updateCount: Int) {
}

class B (val name: String, uc: Int) extends A(uc) {
  def inc(): Unit = {
    updateCount = updateCount + 1
  }
}
```